# How to set state dynamically without declaring it first, in vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

what I'm trying to do is to render a list of categories as a menu, with some nested submenus.
I'm using laravel blade + vuejs.

showSubMenu is a state which can be true or false.

for example by clicking on showSubMenu1, I want to change its state to true to show its submenu div

the problem is that I should declare every state at first in vue, for example:

showSubMenu1 = false,
showSubMenu2 = false,
...

but I don't want to do this, because there is no exact number of categories and also the id of the category table can change whenever a record is deleted, since it's an increment integer

I tried to fix the problem with something like this:

```
@foreach(\App\Models\Category::all() as $category)
                        <li @click="showSubMenu{{$category->id}} = !showSubMenu{{$category->id}}"  ><p>{{$category->name}}</p>
                            <div class="sub-menu"  v-if="showSubMenu{{$category->id}}">
                               
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
```

this method works in react js, since there is no need to specify each state in the state section of the class. but vue complains about it and requires to define each possible state name statically in the vm's data section.

Comment: you could use an object for each submenu state and the key is the category->id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State variables don't have to be simple data types like boolean but can also be object. So you can save all your menu states in one variable:

```
data: () => ({
  activeMenus = {}
}),
methods: {
  isSubMenuVisible(id) {
   return id in this.activeMenus && this.activeMenus === true;
  },
  showSubMenu(id) {
    this.activeMenus[id] = true
  }
}
```